# Using a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I get the following response from the server after doing an ajax request:

```
{"error":false,"success":true}
```

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/update',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response)
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('An error occured, form not submitted.');
    }
});
```

instead of alerting the whole response I want to alert the value of "success", which in this case would be true. How to do this?

Comment: You have to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(response.success);
```

would do it, you can add `dataType: 'json'` to your $.ajax options to make absolutely sure it's evaluated as an object in your callback.

Comment: thanks, adding the dataType did it. I called it right before posting he question but the dataType was required for me.

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
alert(response.success);
```

Comment: @genesis -- yes it will, `$.ajax()` usually knows what type the return is based on the response

Comment: in case Content-Type is application/json. +1 though

Answer (score 3):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {

                        alert(response.success)

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occured, form not submitted.');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alert(response.success);
```