# parse json showing undefined error

Tags: javascript, json

I'm parsing the json to get data but it is showing the undefined error.I'm using the following code.

JSON Data:-

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"vikash","email":"vikash@yahoo.com","phone":"98744254114"},false]
```

javascript:-

```
function getid(id) {
    //document.getElementById('pid').value=id;
    $.ajax({
        url: "page.php?id=" + id,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            var a = console.log(result.name);
            alert(a);

        }
    });
}​
```

Comment: you are parsing an array with the json as first element!

Comment: Well, `result` is an **array** if it was parsed correctly. If not, it is a string which you have to parse first.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
var a = result.name;
```

To:

```
var a = result[0].name;
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/GYr8Q/

Comment: that's because you're capturing the return value from `console.log(' ... ')`; don't - as there is nothing to capture.

Comment: Maybe `result` was not parsed yet. @Ank: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338442/using-a-json-response

Answer (score 0):

Result is an array, to get to the name use `result[0].name`

EDIT

As Felix King suggested the json might not be parsed, if you add a `dataType:'json'` to your ajax call it should be parsed.

```
function getid(id) {
    //document.getElementById('pid').value=id;
    $.ajax({
        url: "page.php?id=" + id,
        dataTpe: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
            var a = console.log(result[0].name);
            alert(a);

        }
    });
}
```